# Using the "on" method for submitting form using classname runs the function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `on("submit", function(){})` to submit a form. i am using a jquery selector that uses the class name.

```
function itinerarioSearh(){
    $("form.itinerario-searchForm").on("submit",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

Now, the problem is that i am dynamically generating the forms and since i have multiple forms with the same classname, the function runs multiple times.

Here is my generated html.

```
<div class="row input_fields_wrap">
<div class="row top-buffer-1">
    <form id="itinerario-searchForm-1" class="itinerario-searchForm">
        <label for="itinerio-localita" class="label-required">Località o città in cui vuoi andare</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required dest-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" id="itinerio-localita" placeholder="" name="itn_countryInput_1" onfocus="replicateItinerarioForm(0);itinerarioAutocomplete(this.id);" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer-1">
    <form id="itinerario-searchForm-2" class="itinerario-searchForm">
        <label for="itinerio-localita" class="label-required">Località o città in cui vuoi andare</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required dest-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" id="itinerio-localita" placeholder="" name="itn_countryInput_1" onfocus="replicateItinerarioForm(1);itinerarioAutocomplete(this.id);" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer-1">
    <form id="itinerario-searchForm-3" class="itinerario-searchForm">
        <label for="itinerio-localita" class="label-required">Località o città in cui vuoi andare</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required dest-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" id="itinerio-localita" placeholder="" name="itn_countryInput_1" onfocus="replicateItinerarioForm(2);itinerarioAutocomplete(this.id);" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer-1">
    <form id="itinerario-searchForm-4" class="itinerario-searchForm">
        <label for="itinerio-localita" class="label-required">Località o città in cui vuoi andare</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required dest-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" id="itinerio-localita" placeholder="" name="itn_countryInput_1" onfocus="replicateItinerarioForm(3);itinerarioAutocomplete(this.id);" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer-1">
    <form id="itinerario-searchForm-5" class="itinerario-searchForm">
        <label for="itinerio-localita" class="label-required">Località o città in cui vuoi andare</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required dest-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" id="itinerio-localita" placeholder="" name="itn_countryInput_1" onfocus="replicateItinerarioForm(4);itinerarioAutocomplete(this.id);" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my console output when i click submit:

```
itinerario-searchForm-1
itinerario-searchForm-1
itinerario-searchForm-1
itinerario-searchForm-1
```

Comment: Where are you calling `itinerarioSearh()`?

Comment: So use a different selector (Hint: ID's are very useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem arise from the fact that you are binding event handler in the `itinerarioSearh()` function, so whenever function is executed a event handler is attached to all existing `$("form.itinerario-searchForm")` due to "direct" binding.

You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to unbind the previously attached event handler before attaching new one.

```
function itinerarioSearh(){
    $("form.itinerario-searchForm").off("submit").on("submit",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

**OR**

Get rid of `itinerarioSearh()` function and use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating forms dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on("submit","form.itinerario-searchForm", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Note: In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken..

You this line..
`$("form.itinerario-searchForm")` searches for `<form>` tag with `itinerario-searchForm`class..

Use `$("#itinerario-searchForm-1")` instead. Hope it works.

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem, but I got the answer. Thanks anyways mate!